# Check if ranges are overlapping

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this:

```
Id  min_val  max_val
1   5        7
2   8        12
3   4        6
```

I want to get True/False if the min_val and max_val are overlapping with any other ID. So, result like below:

```
Id result
1  True  
2  False 
3  True
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from t t2
                where t2.id <> t.id and
                      t2.max_val > t.min_val and
                      t2.min_val < t.max_val
               )
       ) as result;
from t;
```

Another method uses window functions.  It is a bit trickier if periods can start at the same time, but the idea is:

```
select t.*,
       (max(max_val) over (order by min_val range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) > min_val) or
        min(min_val) over (order by max_val desc range between unbounded preceding and current row)
       ) as result
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be overkill but you can use JOINs, as shown below, to not only know if there is an overlap, but what is overlapping:

```
SELECT t.id, tOther.id As overlappingId
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t AS tOther 
   ON t.id <> tOther.id            -- Not the same record
   AND t.min_val < tOther.max_val  -- Starts before "other" ends
   AND t.max_val > tOther.min_val  -- Ends after "other" starts
;
```

If you only want one result row per `t`, the query can be tweaked with aggregation.

```
SELECT t.id
    , COUNT(tOther.id) AS overlappingCount      -- Count ignores null values
    , GROUP_CONCAT(tOther.id) AS overlappingIDs -- Will be null if no overlaps
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t AS tOther 
   ON t.id <> tOther.id            -- Not the same record
   AND t.min_val < tOther.max_val  -- Starts before "other" ends
   AND t.max_val > tOther.min_val  -- Ends after "other" starts
GROUP BY t.id
;
```

If you count a shared bound as overlapping, just change the `>` and `<` to `>=` and `<=` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.id, 

CASE WHEN t2.id IN
(SELECT DISTINCT t.id
FROM tab1 as t
LEFT JOIN tab1 AS t1
WHERE t.id <> t1.id AND (t.min_val < t1.max_val AND t.max_val > t.min_val)) 
THEN "True" ELSE "False" END AS Results

FROM tab1 as t2
```

This works for me. Thanks @Uueerdo and @Gordon Linoff

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` without an `ON` is generally bad form, and in this case basically turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`, which still be more clearly expressed using `ON` rather than `WHERE`. If you want that kind of format for you results you are better off going with Gordon's EXISTS version.

Comment: Thank you @Uueerdo. I did not know this.

Comment: Technically, your solution here would work correctly, it is just structured a bit unconventionally.